# How can I get a log of all incorrectly entered passwords in linux?

Tags: linux, login, password

How can I get a list of all incorrect passwords used whenever someone tried to log in. And how can this be generalized to all types of password fields in linux?

As it mentioned by K1773R, yes it's a not good for security, But i still wanted a temporary solution.

Comment: You could implement http://www.chokepoint.net/2014/01/more-fun-with-pam-python-failed.html

Answer (score 7):

You realy should'nt do this. In case you enter your password with just 1 char wrong, everyone who has access to that list/logfile can guess your password.

Log who and when someone failed to authenticate. What your trying to achieve is a security risk.

Comment: Actually i know that it's a security risk, but i still want to know how can this be archived(Temporarily).

Comment: you should look at honeypots in this case.